# What is the highest version of ag grid react I can use with react-dom 16.6.3?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, ag-grid-react

I am using ag grid react within a react project with react-dom version 16.6.3, I am trying to upgrade the ag grid react (before I was using version 23.2.1), as per the [AG Grid & React Compatibility Chart](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/react-compatibility/), the highest version I can use is 27.1.0, but after upgrading the ag grid packages, and refactor the import statements, I get the below error which I think is due to ag grid not compatible with react-dom.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: react_1.useState is not a function

Please advise how to fix this, or else what is the most version ag grid I should use ?

Comment: I am restricted to React dom version 16.6.3,

Comment: Remove the image and replaced it with the Error

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after reinstalled dependencies